# SharePoint 2010 Backup Failing

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a SharePoint 2010 farm and am attempting to back it up before I upgrade. The backup is failing with 0% complete and all items being stuck in progress with only about 50% of the expected data being written to the backup folders. From what I can tell the problem may be related to a search service failure which I will paste below. The only resolutions I have been able to find for resolving the failed search service is to manually clear the cache and rebuild the server, which I have already tried and it did no resolve my problem. If anyone has any experience dealing with this could you please assist?

Below is the error I'm getting in event viewer for the search service.

Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance (########-####-####-####-############).

Reason: There is no project Portal_Content mounted under gatherer application ########-####-####-####-############.

Technical Support Details:
System.InvalidOperationException: There is no project Portal_Content mounted under gatherer application ########-####-####-####-############16fc3a.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean isAdministrationServiceJob)

Comment: is the search crawl running while you taking the backup?

Comment: No, there is no crawl running.